# How to do multiple if without nested if

Tags: java, if-statement

```
            if (jamholderku.equals("1")){
                params.put("sesi1", jamholderku);
            }else {
                params.put("sesi1", jamholder);
            }

            if (jamholderku2.equals("1")){
                params.put("sesi2", jamholderku2);
            }else {
                params.put("sesi2", jamholder2);
            }

            if (jamholderku3.equals("1")){
                params.put("sesi3", jamholderku3);
            }else {
                params.put("sesi3", jamholder3);
                Log.d("paramskutes", jamholder3);
            }

            if (jamholderku4.equals("1")){
                params.put("sesi4", jamholderku4);
            }else {
                params.put("sesi4", jamholder4);
            }

            if (jamholderku2_1.equals("1")){
                params.put("sesi2_1", jamholderku2_1);
            }else {
                params.put("sesi2_1", jamholder2_1);
            }

            if (jamholderku2_2.equals("1")){
                params.put("sesi2_2", jamholderku2_2);
            }else {
                params.put("sesi2_2", jamholder2_2);
            }

            if (jamholderku2_3.equals("1")){
                params.put("sesi3", jamholderku2_3);
            }else {
                params.put("sesi3", jamholder2_3);
            }

            if (jamholderku2_4.equals("1")){
                params.put("sesi4", jamholderku2_4);
            }else {
                params.put("sesi4", jamholder2_4);
            }

            if (jamholderku3_1.equals("1")){
                params.put("sesi2_1", jamholderku3_1);
            }else {
                params.put("sesi2_1", jamholder3_1);
            }

            if (jamholderku3_2.equals("1")){
                params.put("sesi2_2", jamholderku3_2);
            }else {
                params.put("sesi2_2", jamholder3_2);
            }

            if (jamholderku3_3.equals("1")){
                params.put("sesi3", jamholderku3_3);
            }else {
                params.put("sesi3", jamholder3_3);
            }

            if (jamholderku3_4.equals("1")){
                params.put("sesi4", jamholderku3_4);
            }else {
                params.put("sesi4", jamholder3_4);
            }

            if (jamholderku4_1.equals("1")){
                params.put("sesi2_1", jamholderku4_1);
            }else {
                params.put("sesi2_1", jamholder4_1);
            }

            if (jamholderku4_2.equals("1")){
                params.put("sesi2_2", jamholderku4_2);
            }else {
                params.put("sesi2_2", jamholder4_2);
            }

            if (jamholderku4_3.equals("1")){
                params.put("sesi3", jamholderku4_3);
            }else {
                params.put("sesi3", jamholder4_3);
            }

            if (jamholderku4_4.equals("1")){
                params.put("sesi4", jamholderku4_4);
            }else {
                params.put("sesi4", jamholder4_4);
            }
            return params;
```

when the first if statement right it will not execute other if statement
EX: 
`if (jamholderku.equals("1))` == True
then it will execute params.put(blablabla)
but it won't execute other if statement like `if (jamholderku2.equals("1"))`
but if it executing `if (jamholderku2.equals("1"))`
it won't execute `if (jamholderku3.equals("1"))` even if it was true
can you please help me? because it deadline was due temorrow, i need to submit it or i get kicked from my team

***Addition:***
Example
let's say we using if else

```
if (jamholderku.equals("1")){
    params.put("sesi1", jamholderku);
}else if (jamholderku.equals("0"){
    params.put("sesi1", jamholder);
}else if (jamholderku2.equals("1"){
    params.put("sesi2", jamholder2)
}
```

if the first if true, those else if won't be executed so my database will be null

and if i using nested statement

```
if (jamholderku.equals("1")){
    if (jamholderku2.equals("1"){
        params.put("sesi2", jamholderku2)
    }
   params.put("sesi1", jamholderku)
}
```

if user were selecting session 2 option then only jamholderku2 set to be 1, this make jamholderku false, so all code won't be executed

Edit:
I want to make a program, the program will check, upload, disabling thing.
Here's how it work:
User select date (Ex: 21-01-2020)
User select session, there is 4 session (session 1, session 2, session 3, session 4), and the user only can select 1 session, example user select (session 1)
so the program will upload selected date, and selected session to a server
and when the other user wants to use this program
the second user will need to do step 1 too, but the program will check in the selected date is there is a session that is used by another user
if there is a session that is used by another user, example the first user in date 21-01-2020 select session 1, so the second user when selecting date 21-01-2020, can't select session 1, but still can select session 2, 3, 4
and this program allows user to select multiple date and session

Comment: Your `if` statements don't appear to be nested.  How would you like this code to look?

Comment: i want to make all if being checked because if (jamholderku.equals("1)) == True in the other time it can be False. so i need an if to check all if without being nested

Comment: if i nested that if, when (jamholderku.equals("1)) == True became false, it won't work

Comment: how about using `else if`?

Comment: if one of else if statement were true, then other else if body won't be uploaded to server

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we should all get on the same understanding right now.

This code will check the if-statement and after finding the first TRUE it would stop all checks:

```
String str = "hello";
if(str.equals("hello"){
   dosomething();
} else {
   dosomethingelse();
}
```

So right here it will execute dosomething() and dosomethingelse() will not be executed.

You are giving us an example like this:

```
String str = "huhu";
if(str.equals("hello"){
   dosomething_1();
} else {
   dosomethingelse_1();
}

if(str.equals("huhu"){
   dosomething_2();
} else {
   dosomethingelse_2();
}
```

The if-statements are not nested. The program will check the first if and execute dosomethingelse_1() and after that check the second if and will execute dosomething_2();

Nested if-statement would be something like that:

```
String str = "hello";
if(str.equals("hello"){
   dosomething();
} else {
    if(str.equals("huhu"){
       dosomething();
    } else {
       dosomethingelse();
    }
}
```

And in this case the program would not reach the if(str.equals("huhu")) because it already executed the true one.

So basically we do not understand your question.

Comment: yeah, but I want all if to be executed, so I want the first if to be executed and it will upload those params to the server and second if will execute too if false it will execute else params to the server too

Comment: Right now, just as your code stands as it is, every if-statement will be checked and will result in either true or false. To clarify: the prog will check all of the 16 if-statements you posted.

Comment: and if false the program will post b

Comment: check my new addition on my question

Comment: With your most recent addition I do not understand why you need so many if-statements. Take the date the user had selected, check if this date is already on the server, if it is, check what sessions are used with it and if there are free sessions show that available sessions to the user, otherwise tell him to pick another date.

Comment: to check to server first we need to call it from JSON, if you want to check it api.ayokngaji.com/?orderku , i call JSON from there, i made that JSON by mysef, first i call JSON in android studio, then after calling JSON i check if selectedDate 1 same with server selecteddate1 then call it Selected Session. and i need this statement to put into database